# Symfony and Doctrine making migration with no effect

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Doctrine is generating migration in symfony and nothing changes afer running the migration so during next diff it is the same. How to make Doctrine not generate this migration? Running the alter table command manually does not remove column collation.

```
bin/console doctrine:migration:diff
```

up

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE session CHANGE sess_id sess_id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL');
```

down

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE session CHANGE sess_id sess_id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci');
```

Table looks like that:

```
show create table session;
```

> CREATE TABLE `session` (
>      `sess_id` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>      `sess_data` longblob NOT NULL,
>      `sess_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
>      `sess_lifetime` int(11) NOT NULL,
>      PRIMARY KEY (`sess_id`)
>       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Entity is after adding collation like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="session")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SessionRepository")
 */
class Session
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sess_id", type="string", length=128, options={"collation":"utf8_unicode_ci"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sess_data", type="blob")
     */
    private $sessData;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sess_time", type="integer")
     */
    private $sessTime;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sess_lifetime", type="integer")
     */
    private $sessLifetime;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get sessData
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSessData()
    {
        return $this->sessData;
    }

    /**
     * Set sessData
     *
     * @param string $sessData
     *
     * @return Session
     */
    public function setSessData($sessData)
    {
        $this->sessData = $sessData;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sessTime
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSessTime()
    {
        return $this->sessTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set sessTime
     *
     * @param integer $sessTime
     *
     * @return Session
     */
    public function setSessTime($sessTime)
    {
        $this->sessTime = $sessTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sessLifetime
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSessLifetime()
    {
        return $this->sessLifetime;
    }

    /**
     * Set sessLifetime
     *
     * @param integer $sessLifetime
     *
     * @return Session
     */
    public function setSessLifetime($sessLifetime)
    {
        $this->sessLifetime = $sessLifetime;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.

I use :

- **Symfony**=3.4.9 (flex)

  - doctrine/orm=^2.5.11
- PHP=7.2.5
- cURL=7.59.0
- APCu=5.1.11
- Xdebug=2.6.0
- Composer=1.6.5
- Nginx=1.14.0
- **MariaDB**=10.2.14

### Solution :

For correct my problem, **commented** OR set value **'mariadb-10.2.14'** on the property `server_version` in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`.

Highly inspired by : https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2985

Comment: Thank you so much! Nice to get this fixed.  Just to add for future reference, if someone needs to find their MariaDB version to set this value, just execute SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

Comment: You can also execute in terminal `mysql -V` to see mariadb version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to column annotation:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(options={"collation":"utf8_unicode_ci"})
 */
private $sess_id;
```

Comment: Now the up and down migrations are exactly the same
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE session CHANGE sess_id sess_id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci');

Comment: did you try to run this: `doctrine:clear:metadata:cache`

Comment: Clearing cache did not work. I even deleted whole var/cache folder

Answer (score 0):

This is because you creating $id column, type string, with `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")`

remove: `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")`