# Symfony 4 make:migration doesn't work when ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I followed this example :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

But when I make :

`php bin/console make:migration`

Here is my migration file :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20191121114152 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE category (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE product (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE category');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE product');
    }
}
```

Doctrine stops after the id field. He doesn't see the others.

**Has anyone ever had this problem?**

---

**My config is :**

- Wamp (Windows 10, MySQL 5.7)
- Symfony 4.3

---

**My Entity Class :**

Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->addCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products->removeElement($product);
            $product->removeCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Product.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
     */
    private $category;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->category = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Category[]
     */
    public function getCategory(): Collection
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function addCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->category->contains($category)) {
            $this->category[] = $category;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if ($this->category->contains($category)) {
            $this->category->removeElement($category);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcomne! For your problem it would be more beneficial if you could provide us how the migrations itself is executed either via `artisan migrate` command or with `artisan migrate:refresh`.

Comment: Could you include your entity classes, their mapping, and any errors you are getting?

Comment: @Kyrre I added the entity classes. I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved ! (Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909114/symfony-and-doctrine-making-migration-with-no-effect))

The problem came from the declaration of the mysql version.

My Wamp uses precisely version 5.7.26

So I had to put 5.7.26 in the Doctrine configuration file.

Thank you for your comments.